# Como gerar listas tendo como nome um item de outra lista?

Tags: python

É um programa que lê planilha do Excel com lançamentos de débito e crédito em uma conta.

```
abreexcel2.py

def leplanilha():
   wb1 = oxl.load_workbook('extratomar2018.xlsx')
   folhas=wb1.get_sheet_names()
   print(folhas)
   sheet=wb1.get_sheet_by_name('plan1')
   nr=sheet.max_row
   nc=sheet.max_column
   for rw in range(2,nr+1):
      if sheet['D'+str(rw)].value in lista:
         pass
      else:
         lista.append(sheet['D'+str(rw)].value)
   print(lista)
leplanilha():
```

Gerou a seguinte lista:

> ['TEDSALARIO', 'APLIC POUP', 'CP MAESTRO', 'DOC ELET', 'DEB.IOF', 'SAQUE B24H', 'PAG FONE', 'PG PREFEIT', 'PAG AGUA', 'PAG BOLETO', 'ENVIO TEV', 'DEP CH 24H', 'CRED TED', 'RESG POUP', 'DOC ELET E', 'DEB CESTA', 'CHEQ COMP', 'SAQUE ATM', 'PG LUZ/GAS']

Pergunta: gostaria de gerar uma lista automaticamente, tendo como nome cada um desses elementos dessa lista, para preenchê-los, com os respectivos lançamentos, mas não consigo.

Como gerar uma variável tendo como nome um item de uma lista?

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer criar as listas com o nome no código fonte, então você precisa criar um arquivo e imprimir o novo código com os nomes que você quer respeitando a sintaxe da linguagem.

Contudo, é mais simples usar uma variável dicionário, onde cada nome será uma chave para uma lista, por exemplo:

```
>>> nome_lista = 'SAQUE ATM'
>>> dicionario = {}
>>> dicionario[nome_lista] = [1,2,3]
>>> print (dicionario['SAQUE ATM'])
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Gean. Acho melhor fazer como dicionário mesmo.